# Why doesn't this function return the last full line in a serial file?

Tags: c, linux, arduino, serial-port

I am writing a c library to assist in reading from an arduino controller on linux. My arduino code writes the value of each of its inputs (a joystick and two buttons) seperated by a comma to /dev/ttyACM0 once every 1/3 of a second. My C code should print out the second to last line, AKA the line that was last completed but instead it just prints out an empty line. Here's my code:

```
char* getLastFullLine() {
    FILE* fd = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "r");
    /* max length including newline */
    static const long max_len = 55 + 1;
    /* space for all of that plus a nul terminator */
    char buf[max_len + 1];

    /* now read that many bytes from the end of the file */
    fseek(fd, -max_len, SEEK_END);
    fread(buf, max_len, 1, fd);

    /* don't forget the nul terminator */
    buf[max_len - 1] = '\0';
    char *last_newline;
    /* and find the last newline character (there must be one, right?) */
    last_newline = strrchr(buf, '\n');
    return last_newline;
}
int main() {
    printf("%s \n", getLastFullLine());
}
```

Comment: The file name `/dev/ttyACM0` represents a serial *terminal* device, not a *"serial file"*.  It is not a stream, and should be accessed with **open()** and **read()** syscalls (and properly configured).   *"My C code should print out the second to last line"* -- Trying to synchronize your program execution with data reception is foolish.  Modern Linux will not buffer data for an unopened serial terminal.  IOW when you open/fopen the serial terminal *after* the data has received (and discarded), your program has no data to read (until new data is received).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues: don't return a stack addr for reuse,
switch `buf[]` to a global or static;
`fseek()` return value is being ignored, what happens if there's an error?
based on the original args, `fread()` success could yield 1
but the actual read byte count is needed;
terminating `buf[]` assumed that `buf[]` was filled by the `fread()`
though fewer bytes are possible,
better to terminate after actual byte count that was read;
there was no accounting for the last byte read being a '\n',
`strrchr()` could find that.

Does your device support seek?

As an informal starting point, try this version with a large enough regular file then switch to your device:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFSIZE 55
char buf[BUFSIZE + 1];


char *
getLastFullLine(void)
{
    char *fname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
    int fd;
    off_t max_len;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *ptr;
    long lsr;

    // tmp for testing
    fname = "infile";

    fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("\"%s\" open error\n", fname);
        return (NULL);
    }

    max_len = BUFSIZE;
    lsr = (long) lseek(fd, -max_len, SEEK_END);
    if (lsr < 0) {
        printf("lseek error, %ld\n", lsr);
        return (NULL);
    }
    nread = read(fd, buf, max_len);
    close(fd);
    printf("nread %zd\n", nread);

    ptr = &buf[nread];
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    // ignore last byte if LF
    if (*ptr == '\n')
        *ptr = '\0';
    // printf("buf \"%s\"\n", buf);

    if ((ptr = strrchr(buf, '\n')) == NULL)
        ptr = buf;
    return (ptr);
}

int
main(void)
{
    printf("last line:\n%s\n", getLastFullLine());
    return (0);
}
```